# Add angle of point from road as seen from left to right?

Tags: qgis, vector, geometry, angles, parcel

[image]

I have a layer of trees (purple points) that I want to add a column that equals the order of trees by angle if seen from left to right. For example, with the property with three trees, you would stand on the street facing the parcel (The star, perpendicular to the centroid) and turn to the left looking down the street. Then you would scan a 180 degree arc, first noting the tree marked 1, then 2, then 3, until you are looking straight down the road again. The trees are then marked 1, 2 3, etc. This would be repeated for every parcel with a tree associated (there is a parcel id field associated with each tree). Is there a way to get these angles?

Comment: I am standing at the intersection of the road centerline and the line stemming from the green dots

Comment: I updated the image. For the parcel with three points, you are standing on the star and then you see points one two and three as you sweep from left to right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this (complicated code) to work you need:

- To join each plot id, to the "centroid lines" and the trees.
- The centroid lines need to start in the street, and end at each plot
- Extract the centroid lines start points with "geometry by expression" and `start_point($geometry)`

The code will for each plot, order/sort the trees accourding to their clockwise orientation around the centroid lines start point, and add their order to a field.

```
from collections import defaultdict as dd
import math
trees = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('tree')[0]
treeOrderField = 'treeOrder' #The field to calculate, add this integer field before executing the code
plotIdField = 'plotid' #The plot identifier field


startPointCoordinates = {} #A dictionary of start point id as key, x,y coordinates as values
for start_point in QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('centroid_lines_start_points')[0].getFeatures():
    geom = start_point.geometry().asPoint()
    startPointCoordinates[start_point[plotIdField]] = [geom.x(), geom.y()]
#{53444: [671656.8246994428, 6589063.457420763], 
#53445: [671684.0503341975, 6589075.071879962], 
#...}

treesPerPlot = dd(list)

for tree in trees.getFeatures():
    treesPerPlot[tree[plotIdField]].append(tree)

#For each plot id, a list of all trees:
#defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {64245: [<qgis._core.QgsFeature object at 0x7fc323f1b820>, <qgis._core.QgsFeature object at 0x7fc323f1b670>, <qgis._core.QgsFeature object at 0x7fc323f1b790>], 
#                             53446: [<qgis._core.QgsFeature object at 0x7fc323f1b4c0>], 53445: [<qgis._core.QgsFeature object at 0x7fc323f1b5e0>, <qgis._core.QgsFeature object at 0x7fc323f1b3a0>, <qgis._core.QgsFeature object at 0x7fc323f1b040>]})

fieldindex = trees.fields().indexFromName(treeOrderField)
attributeMap = {}
for plotid, treelist in treesPerPlot.items():
    trees_sorted_clockwise = sorted(treelist, key=lambda x: math.atan2((x.geometry().asPoint().y()-startPointCoordinates[x[plotIdField]][1]), -(x.geometry().asPoint().x()-startPointCoordinates[x[plotIdField]][0])))
    for treenumber, tree in enumerate(trees_sorted_clockwise, 1):
        attributeMap[tree.id()] = {fieldindex:treenumber}
#{3: {-1: 1}, 2: {-1: 2}, 1: {-1: 3}, 4: {-1: 1}, 7: {-1: 1}, 6: {-1: 2}, 5: {-1: 3}}
#tree with id 3, should in field with index -1, get tree number 1

trees.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues(attributeMap)
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent, it works now that I have removed the minus sign